# Not able to Build Xcode Project using Jenkins & Pods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jenkins, cocoapods, jenkins-plugins

We are using Jenkins 2.62. When trying to build from Jenkins, I am getting the errors below:

> [workspace] $ /bin/bash -l /var/folders/km/33wcncls1874x2xv50nv43480000gn/T/jenkins1804164065511577211.sh
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:318:in `to_specs': Could not find 'claide' (< 2.0, >= 1.0.0) among 32 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
>   Checked in 'GEM_PATH=file:/Users/administrator/.jenkins/plugins/ruby-runtime/WEB-INF/lib/stapler-jruby-1.209.jar!/gem:/Users/administrator/Software/ruby', execute`gem env`for more information
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1402:in`block in activate_dependencies'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `each'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in`activate_dependencies'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1373:in `activate'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in`block in gem'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `synchronize'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in`gem'
>       from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `'

Below is the script we are using in **Execute Shell**

```
**rm -fr *.xcworkspace
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
rm -fr Pods/
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
/usr/local/bin/pod install
xcodebuild -workspace Proj.xcworkspace -scheme Proj_test -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/Proj/Build/Release-iphoneos/Proj.xcarchive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/ChannelConnect/Build/Release-iphoneos/Proj.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ${WORKSPACE}/exportOptionsPlist.plist -exportPath ${WORKSPACE}/Proj/Build/Release-iphoneos**
```

When we tried "Pod Install" for the same path in the server manually, it worked just fine.

Can we change the Jenkins pods path?

Comment: Maybe u have multiple cocoapods versions installed, what's the output of `which -a pod` ?

Comment: I think there are two pods Below is the Output 
/usr/local/bin/pod
/Users/administrator/Software/ruby/bin/pod

Comment: Okay and what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/administrator/kiranm/software/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:/Users/administrator/Software/ruby/bin

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Jenkins messes with your `PATH`. This is very common. You have to explicitly tell Jenkins to add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH.

1. See the current contents under `System Information -> Environment Variables` to validate this theory.
2. Adjust the value under `Configure System -> Environment Variables` by adding `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`
3. If you have slaves, you'll have to configure it for each of them under `Manage Nodes -> Node -> System Info`

Comment: Thanks Sven, I tried the steps and added the path in Enveronmental Varible s check the URL https://ibb.co/isU5JF but still facing the same issue, do we need to restart the Jenkins?

Comment: Yes try a restart. If this doesn't work, try to set the env var for your build node also (+ restart). Always validate against the displayed env vars under System Information. Oh and please append `/Users/administrator/Software/ruby` also to your custom PATH value. Seems like there are some gems installed at that path

Comment: Will the path like below
/usr/local/bin: /Users/administrator/Software/ruby/$PATH

Comment: That's not a valid path. Try /usr/bin/local:/Users/administrator/Software/ruby:$PATH

Comment: Still facing the issue, in the System Information I am getting the following path /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/administrator/kiranm/software/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:/Users/administrator/Software/ruby/bin:/Users/administrator/Software/ruby/bin

Comment: Yeah right my mistake, the trailing /bin is missing after /ruby ... Basically you just have to copy-paste all the relevant PATH entries to the Jenkins config